# Safely auto increment MySQL field based on MAX() subquery upon insert

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have a table which contains a standard auto-incrementing ID, a type identifier, a number, and some other irrelevant fields. When I insert a new object into this table, the number should auto-increment based on the type identifier.

Here is an example of how the output should look:

```
id      type_id     number
1       1           1
2       1           2
3       2           1
4       1           3   
5       3           1
6       3           2
7       1           4
8       2           2
```

As you can see, every time I insert a new object, the number increments according to the type_id (i.e. if I insert an object with type_id of 1 and there are 5 objects matching this type_id already, the number on the new object should be 6).

I'm trying to find a performant way of doing this with huge concurrency. For example, there might be 300 inserts within the same second for the same type_id and they need to be handled sequentially.

### Methods I've tried already:

#### PHP

This was a bad idea but I've added it for completeness. A request was made to get the MAX() number for the item type and then add the number + 1 as part of an insert. This is quick but doesn't work concurrently as there could be 200 inserts between the request for MAX() and that particular insert leading to multiple objects with the same number and type_id.

#### Locking

Manually locking and unlocking the table before and after each insert in order to maintain the increment. This caused performance issues due to the number of concurrent inserts and because the table is constantly read from throughout the app.

#### Transaction with Subquery

This is how I'm currently doing it but it still causes massive performance issues:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO objects (type_id,number) VALUES ($type_id, (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(number),0)+1 FROM objects WHERE type_id = $type_id FOR UPDATE));
COMMIT;
```

Another negative thing about this approach is that I need to do a follow up query in order to get the number that was added (i.e. searching for an object with the $type_id ordered by number desc so I can see the number that was created - this is done based on a $user_id so it works but adds an extra query which I'd like to avoid)

#### Triggers

I looked into using a trigger in order to dynamically add the number upon insert but this wasn't performant as I need to perform a query on the table I'm inserting into (which isn't allowed so has to be within a subquery causing performance issues).

#### Grouped Auto-Increment

I've had a look at grouped auto-increment (so that the number would auto-increment based on type_id) but then I lose my auto-increment ID.

---

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can make this performant at the level of concurrent inserts that I need? My table is currently InnoDB on MySQL 5.5

Appreciate any help!

**Update:** Just in case it is relevant, the objects table has several million objects in it. Some of the `type_id` can have around 500,000 objects assigned to them.

Comment: My though is - use group auto-increment. That is - about - if your `<type_id, number>` is unique (and it must be - due to your logic) - it can be primary key, so what's the sense in surrogate `id` key? You even seeking a way to determine correct row address with your combination, so `id` then is redundant. If it's purpose is to keep consecutive numbering - why do not apply it in application? So it looks like your question is about __how to maintain TWO primary keys in table?__ - and that's a fault by design

Comment: That sounds like an interesting idea. My issue with that change is that the application is already running and there are several million objects with IDs which I'm joining on. As a basic example, each object can have many 'Comments' attached to it which are done by having an `object_id` on the Comment table. How would I link these two together if I drop the existing primary key and work on `<type_id,number>`? I've never used anything other than the standard `id` pattern with primary, auto-increment before.

Comment: Huh, that can be an idea, but you have `InnoDB`. It doesn't support multiple column auto_increment. So that's not an option, sorry

Comment: Technically, I could change the `id` column from being an int to a varchar and then generate a UUID on insert. This would allow me to keep the surrogate key so all my previous joins, etc, work but means I wouldn't have two auto-increments? Do you think that would make sense?

Comment: You can't use auto_increment to generate `number` values automatically because that mechanics works only for `BDB` and `MyISAM` storage-engines

Comment: Do, it isn't - as it's described in [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) for version 5.5

Comment: Ah no it isn't. I'd read on another SO that it was now supported and thought I'd tested it but a quick play with it now shows that it doesn't work with InnoDB.

Comment: But before posting that, I've checked. No, that's not supported. Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c69b7) and try to replace `MyISAM` to `InnoDB` within table's definition and see that it will not be allowed

Comment: Why *store* `number` at all? Why not just calculate it 'on-the-fly'?

Answer (score 1):

Use transaction and select ... for update. This will solve concurrency conflicts.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I'm already doing this (the code is even in the question) but it causes performance issues as it doesn't seem to be able to handle lots of inserts at the same time very well.

Comment: May be you just have slow select statement? You mention, that you use index on type_id, may be two-column index on type_id and number will help?

Answer (score 0):

In **Transaction with Subquery**

Try to make **index** on column **type_id**

I think by making index on column type_id it will speed up your subquery.

Comment: There is already an index but it is still too slow. There are several million entries in that table.

Comment: may i view structure of your table with all columns and data types??

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table 
 (id      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,type_id     INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,1),(5,3),(6,3),(7,1),(8,2);

 SELECT x.*
      , COUNT(*) rank 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.type_id = x.type_id 
    AND y.id <= x.id 
  GROUP 
     BY id 
  ORDER 
     BY type_id
      , rank;

 +----+---------+------+
 | id | type_id | rank |
 +----+---------+------+
 |  1 |       1 |    1 |
 |  2 |       1 |    2 |
 |  4 |       1 |    3 |
 |  7 |       1 |    4 |
 |  3 |       2 |    1 |
 |  8 |       2 |    2 |
 |  5 |       3 |    1 |
 |  6 |       3 |    2 |
 +----+---------+------+
```

or, if performance is an issue, just do the same thing with a couple of @variables.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. I'm looking to store the number in the database at the time of insert, not work it out from a select afterwards.

Comment: Because the number of the object needs to be stored. There are several million objects in the table so I don't want to have to generate it on the fly every time I'm displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an idea to create a (temporary) table for all rows with a common "type_id".
In that table you can use auto-incrementing for your num colomn.
Then your num shoud be fully trustable.
Then you can select your data and update your first table.